# Kind of wood with deep brown streaks?

Tags: wood, wood-species

I was in the [Field Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_Museum_of_Natural_History) a couple of weeks ago and at the end of the new China exhibit is the "Cyrus Tang" spirit stone display. The wood flooring was extremely interesting, being a blond wood with heavy streaks of dark brown:

[image]

What kind of wood is this?

Comment: What I will presume is the image source http://www.fieldmuseum.org/discover/on-exhibit/china/

Comment: Also after searching for about 20 minutes I found the answer you are looking for. It is bamboo. More specifically: _The exhibit also features PlybooStrand (Neopolitan) for the flooring_. You can read up on it and follow the links from this page. http://intectural.com/case-study-field-museum-chose-plyboo-bamboo-new-china-exhibit/. Actual product page that shows the pictures that nearly match above: http://www.plyboo.com/products/plyboostrand-bamboo-flooring. Since I VTC this question I don't feel it is right to answer this one.

Comment: I removed the close vote as this question has a definite answer. Please note that normally questions like these are off topic: http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/53/are-wood-identification-questions-allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image you have came from the [Field Museum](http://www.fieldmuseum.org/discover/on-exhibit/china/) obviously. In trying to look for plans or a source as to what the floor was made of I found a ["case study"](http://intectural.com/case-study-field-museum-chose-plyboo-bamboo-new-china-exhibit/) from the manufacturer that talks about the wood used in the exhibit. The quote from the site reads like an ad but it does talk about the flooring specifically used.

> The exhibit also features **PlybooStrand (Neopolitan) for the flooring**. Plyboo was a perfect fit for this exhibit, as it comes from the Moso bamboo forests of China. A sustainable building material, it is made from 100% FSC-certified bamboo, which is rapidly renewable and free of urea formaldehyde. Plyboo is also extremely durable, an important consideration for such a heavy-trafficked environment.

It was easy after that to find the [product page for the flooring](http://www.plyboo.com/products/plyboostrand-bamboo-flooring) quoted.

[image: PlybooStrand (Neopolitan)]

<sup>Image of PlybooStrand Neopolitan from [plyboo.com](http://www.plyboo.com/products/plyboostrand-bamboo-flooring)</sup>

And as [Treow Wyrhta](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/users/306/treow-wyrhta)'s [answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/2824/128) shows this is not wood but an engineered wood product. So in this case there is no grey area about the wood in question.

Comment: Normally I would not entertain these questions but I feel this Q&A works because I know what the wood is and there is no speculation.

Comment: Note that some of these bamboo-based products, and some of the other new "sustainable" materials, can be gotten as dimensional lumber for non-floor projects. You may have to special-order them, though, and they are still not cheap.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it is a not a hard wood, but a synthetic bamboo plywood. The manufacturer, Intectural, describes it as:

> PlybooStrand uses strand technology to turn 100% rapidly renewable
>   bamboo into a beautiful yet exceptionally durable green building
>   material for both commercial and residential use. Strand differs from
>   typical bamboo material in that the bamboo is not cut into strips and
>   laminated, but instead thrashed and pressed into dense logs. The logs
>   are sliced and fabricated into plywood, creating a harder, denser
>   material with an entirely new bamboo aesthetic.